# Karnaugh Map for an expression with two terms

Tags: boolean-algebra

When I have an expression such as:
$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)= \sum m(1,4,7)+ D(2,5)$

What do I do with the part D(2,5)? Do I make a second k-map just for that term and OR(+) it to the expression or should I just put the terms (2,5) in the original k-map and find the expression that way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, you should make 4 different K-maps trying all possible $0$ and $1$ combinations in the places of don't cares and see which K-map minimization gives the simplest expression.

In practice, it is cumbersome to carry out the principle. So we put a star in the K-map, in the place of don't cares and try to do the computation faster.

The answer to your problem is $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1\overline{x_2} + x_3\overline{x_2} + x_1x_3$. Among the two don't cares, the don't care $5$ helps, but the don't care $2$ does not help.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You should use one Karnaugh map with [don't cares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map#Don.27t_cares) inputs $x$ as it is shown on picture bellow:

[image]

So minimized function is $f(X_1,X_2,X_3)=(X_1\land \neg X_2)\lor (X_1\land X_3)\lor  (\neg X_2\land X_3)$